# C# sockets wont work with flash in this case

Tags: c#, php, sockets, flash

Currently i am using that as daemon via XAMPP shell... but, maybe any ways to make them on C# as
"server" app instead using php daemon? I following examples from MSDN, like that: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y0e13d3(v=vs.110).aspx
But my simple Flash App wont work with various "samples" from MSDN... I put writelines on all connect events (handle first connect, recieve data, etc...)
but they simple wont work... But with that php daemon - everything works like a charm... How i can do this on the right way with C#?

```
    <?php

    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    $fileTest = 'test.txt';

    socket_bind($socket, "127.0.0.1", 843);
    socket_listen($socket, 90);

    while($client = socket_accept($socket)){

        echo "\nWorked \n";
        // Print client connections
        if(socket_getpeername($client, $address, $port)) {
            echo "\nClient $address has connected on port $port \n";
        }

        // Ensure client is requesting our file
        $buf = socket_read($client, 2048);
        echo "Client $address has requested: $buf \n";
        // Send our file to client
        echo "Sending $fileTest  contents back to $address \n";
        if (file_exists($fileTest)) {
        $pFile = file($fileTest);
        $pFile = join('',$pFile);
        socket_write($client, $pFile . "\0");
        socket_close($client);
        } else {
          echo "Error! Our file is not here =/";
        }
    }

    socket_close($socket);
?>
```